# WSOD on deploy: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: files, wsod

I am trying to deploy a site to a live server, but running into a "white screen of death". Enabling logs revealed that the zurb foundation starter theme was the source of my issues, so I disabled that and was able to use the site. I then switched it back on and went straight into white screen of death again.

Then I used drush to get a login url and accesed /admin where I could so the following list of errors:

https://gist.github.com/webconsult/a82eebc3d25480f674ed

I checked, and it seems these files and functions are all present. I'm not sure if the ownership settings are correct, though, but I am assuming the apache user is able to read and execute the fieles correctly since everything works if I switch away from the Zurb Foundation theme (i.e. Garland theme). Here is a sample of ownership and permission of the files in /includes:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin  13816 Mar 19 18:30 actions.inc
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin  48742 Mar 19 18:30 ajax.inc
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin   1701 Mar 19 18:30 archiver.inc
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin  13664 Mar 19 18:30 authorize.inc
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin  17497 Mar 19 18:30 batch.inc
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin   2310 Mar 19 18:30 batch.queue.inc
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 119919 Mar 19 18:30 bootstrap.inc
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is a file permissions overview on this [page](https://www.drupal.org/node/244924) of how all file permissions should be setup. If you will scroll down to the bottom of the documentation page there is a shell script that you can install and run on an entire Drupal installation that will fix all file permission issues. That should fix any problems that OP was having.